# global variable not recognised when declared in procedure

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Can anyone tell me why the global variable y is not being recognised in the below code please?

```
proc add_new_seq {} {
global y 2
rid .kl15_val -row $y -column 4
incr y
}
add_new_seq
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command "global y 2" declares 2 global variables, named y and 2 respectively (yes, in Tcl 2 is a perfectly valid variable name). Neither of the variables has a value yet. You may have intended:

```
global y
set y 2
```

But that would reset the variable to 2 every time. So you probably want something along the lines of:

```
set y 2
proc add_new_seq {} {
    global y
    rid .kl15_val -row $y -column 4
    incr y
}
add_new_seq
```